# Calculating the resulting voltage of two capacitors

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

I've an exercise and I'm not sure that I solved it well, so this is it:

What is the resulting voltage of the circuit if two capacitors (3 µF and 6 µF) are connected in series and the energy of the 3 µF capacitor is 15 mWs?

Here's my solution:

W = 1/2·C·U<sup>2</sup>
15·10<sup>-3</sup> = 1/2·3·10<sup>-6</sup>·U1<sup>2</sup>
10000 = U1<sup>2</sup>
100 V = U1

U = U1 + U2 = 150 V

Q = C·U
In series -> Q1 = Q2
U1 = U + U2

Q1 = C1·U1 = 3·10<sup>-6</sup>·100 = 3·10<sup>-4</sup>

U2 = Q2/C2 = 3·10<sup>-4</sup>/6·10<sup>-6</sup> = 50 V

U = U1 + U2 = 150 V

Thanks for the review and remarks!

Comment: We do not know the energy of the 6 uF capacitor. Who is to say it contains any energy?

Comment: If the two capacitor is in series, and one of them contains energy it means that the other capacitor must have voltage as well, because the same current flows on both.

Comment: So we're making the assumption that the 2 capacitors were in series at t0, and that at t0 they both had no charge, and that they remained in series while some current was made to flow through them until such time as the 3µF capacitor was charged to 15mWs?

Comment: Actually the exercise asks, the generator voltage in the circuit, while the two capacitor (3 uF and 6 uF) are in series, and the energy of the 3 uF capacitor is given which is 15 mWs.

Comment: @NorbertKts mW is not a unit of energy, but a unit of power. Do you mean mJ?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy The measure unit of capacitor's energy is equivalent with Joule, so Ws [Watt / seconds = Joule ], 
Ws = Joule , or you didn't mean this?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy a recent edit has incorrectly changed the OP's question from mWs (milli-Watt-seconds) to just mW.

Comment: @ocrdu please be more careful when you (unnecessarily imo) edit others' questions to put spaces between values and their units.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Oh I see that, so I guess you meant mWs.

Comment: @NorbertKts I apologize, I didn't notice that the mWs had been edited to mW.

Answer (score 1):

The 3uF capacitor will have 100V across it @ 15mJ of stored energy. The resulting voltage of the 2 capacitors in series is: 100V + V(6uF).